# Cannot access Outlook pst file

Tags: microsoft-outlook

One day recently my  Outlook failed to open. The error message was as follows:

> "Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. The set of folders cannot be opened.
>   File access is denied. You do not have the permission required to
>   access the file.
>   C:\Users\57gar_000\Documents\OutlookFiles\martindavis@ramidus.co.uk.pst."

I examined the pst file - I had full permissions, there was no read only box ticked. I then used the scanpst utility to repair the file. Repairs made, but still no joy. Advice?

Comment: Quick suggestions.... `1.` Reboot the machine... `2.` copy the PST file to another location with Outlook close and then try linking it up from the other location `3.` define a new Outlook profile and try linking it up again afterwards.... Quick ideas only.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new mail profile with the same credentials as the old account via **Control Panel > Mail (Microsoft Outlook [year])** and set it as the default or set it to prompt you for a profile when Outlook opens.

[image]

Now open Outlook and load the new profile. Go into **File > Account Settings > Data Files > Add** to import the PST into Outlook.

[image]